# Javascript: Solving the asynchronous loop to push an array in Parse.com

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, promise

I'd like to get the final result from a loop where I'm pushing objects into an array.  I know from the console.log that all of the results go into the array but I can't get my desired array out of the double loop to use for anything.  I understand that you could use callbacks or promises and I'll take either solution (Parse Promises is installed).

The code:

```
var arrayNames = {key: val}
var val = {k: v, k1: v, k2: v}
var array = [];
var find= function(arrayNames) {
     _.mapObject(arrayNames, function (val, key) {
         _.mapObject(val, function (v, k) {
              var person = Parse.Object.extend("People");
              var query = new Parse.Query(person);
              query.equalTo("name", k);
              query.find({
                  success: function (row) {
                  var rowsToUpdate = _.uniq(row);
                  array.push(rowsToUpdate);
                  console.log(array);
                 }
              })
           })
         })
}

var newfunc = function(array){
     //Do Something with the array that's full of the results from find();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you achieve this by some simple refactoring?

```
var newfunc = function(callback){
     console.log(callback);//this is now a bunch of arrays in 
     //my console log instead of a single one
}

var arrayNames = {key: val}
var val = {k: v, k1: v, k2: v}
var array = [];

// move 'newfunc' declaration to be above 'find'
var newfunc = function(array){
     //Do Something with the array that's full of the results from find();
     console.log(array);
}

var find= function(arrayNames) {
     _.mapObject(arrayNames, function (val, key) {
         _.mapObject(val, function (v, k) {
              var person = Parse.Object.extend("People");
              var query = new Parse.Query(person);
              query.equalTo("name", k);
              query.find({
                  success: function (row) {
                     var rowsToUpdate = _.uniq(row);
                     array.push(rowsToUpdate);
                     console.log(array);

                     // "callback" to 'newfunc' passing in the success results
                     newfunc(array);
                 }
              })
           })
         })
}
```

by moving `newfunc` above the `find` function we make sure it is defined first and ready to go when the `find` function executes

we then use execute `newfunc` as a within the `success` callback

Comment: Actually, that's the way I have it in my latest iteration and I will edit it to reflect that.  When I console log the call back quantity, it sends each push to array instead a single array with all of the rowsToUpdate within.  To be clear newfunc should receive a single array with all rowsToUpdate instead of 'N' rows to upDate, calling newfunc 'N' times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the promises returned by `query.find()`.

Assuming the nested `_.mapObject()` calls to be correct, then something like this should work :

```
var find = function(arrayNames) {
    var promises = [];
    _.mapObject(arrayNames, function (val, key) {
        _.mapObject(val, function (v, k) {
            var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("People"));
            query.equalTo("name", k);
            promises.push(query.find());
        });
    });
    return Parse.when(promises).then(function() {
        newfunc(_.uniq([].slice.call(arguments)));
    });
}
```

I'm  not convinced that `_.mapObject()` is the best method here, but if it works ...